# How to register a JPA Listener for a specific JPA Persistence Unit

Tags: jpa, entitylisteners

My application has multiple persistence units and I want a listener registered to just one.  The orm.xml spec seems to just make them default for both.

How do I explicitly map a listener to a given persistence unit(s)?

Comment: A listener can be registered to a class (via `orm.xml`), not a persistence-unit. The only place where you can define things on a unit basis is in `persistence.xml` and there is no provision for only applying the listener in one unit (other than only having the class accessible under 1 persistence unit)

Comment: I was hoping to not have to restrict it at that level, but that looks like it is more and more the only route I can go.

Comment: Well I suppose the clue is in the name "entity listener" (i.e on a class by class basis) as to why they haven't provided such a mechanism. That said, it would be a very useful addition IMHO. You could register it as a JPA issue over at https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jpa-api/issues and somebody may include it in a future version, not that it helps you now

Comment: I am going to disable the default entity listeners for specific classes/entities as that will work for now, but will just need to be aware of that and downstream impacts if I want or need to listen to events from persisting those entities ...